# Error running polygonize from QGIS!

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, polygonize

I'm trying to vectorize a raster image and when I'm running polygonize within QGIS 2.6.1. I'm getting the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin\gdal_polygonize.py", line 36, in  import
>   gdal, ogr, osr  ImportError: No module named gdal

I know that gdal is installed.
I don't know what to do! Need help!

Comment: Have you tried unchecking GdalTools from the _Manage and Install Plugins..._ menu > restart QGIS > re-check GdalTools from menu?

Comment: Did that. Restarted 2 times. The same error...

Comment: Perhaps uninstall and then reinstall QGIS might solve the problem?

Comment: I've installed a new copy of Qgis and still the problem persists.

Comment: If you haven't done so, try running via _Raster_ > _Conversion_ > _Polygonize_ or via the _Processing Toolbox_. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas and hopefully others can advise :)